# MaterialUI - Indepdendent Grids next to each other?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Grid container and two "sub-containers" each taking half the space of the parent grid. I want to stack items of different heights on each of the sub-containers, but I'm having a problem with one side's height affecting the other.
The code is extremely simple:

```
<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item container xs={6}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Item>Short items</Item>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Item>Short items</Item>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Item>Short items</Item>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item container xs={6}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Item style={{ height: "450px" }}>Tall item</Item>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
```

And also a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autogrid-material-demo-forked-yf0e6?file=/demo.tsx) forked from the documentation's. The result I want is the items on the left stacking right on top of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `alignContent="baseline"` to your left `Grid` container like:

```
<Grid item container xs={6} alignContent="baseline">
```

You can take a look at [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mui-aligned-grids) for a live working example of this usage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm still on v4 so I had to use `alignContent='flex-start'` instead of 'baseline' but other than that it worked 100%.